# Firefox 13 iframe print issues from javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

Can't get this to print on FF 13. No javascript errors, just doesn't do anything. Any advice?

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function print_app(){
        $('#content')[0].focus();
        $('#content')[0].contentWindow.print();
    }
    $('#print').click( function(){
        print_app();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="print">PRINT</div>
<iframe id="content" name="content" src="pto.pdf" 
style="width: 100%; height: 745px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: If you're loading a PDF file, there may be no "window" object; a PDF file isn't an HTML document.

Comment: `console.log($('#content')[0].contentWindow)` shows an object.

Comment: Oh wait - you're clicking on the PDF itself?  Have you tried seeing if handling a "click" on a button or something makes it work? It could be that Firefox doesn't propagate "click" events from the `<iframe>` to the outer containing document.

Comment: Oh sorry; durr I thought the `<div>` wrapped around the `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to put a print function in the iframe and call it from the parent

iFrame:

```
    function printThis() {
    window.print();
    }
```

Parent:

```
    document."iframeid".printThis();
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to add javascript to the pdf.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.bugfree.dk/blog/2009/12/17/printing-iframe-content-using-javascript/